# Google BQ Web UI - is there a 'Run Selected' keyboard shortcut?

Tags: google-bigquery

Think the title covers it.

Just wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut for the 'run selected' drop down on the web ui.

Would be great if there was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Ctrl+E.

The list of supported keyboard shortcuts is here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-web-ui#keyboardshortcuts

Comment: Thanks for update. It was some scary moments of missing some features after yesterday release deploy. I guessed it will be rolledback - I am glad it was. Meantime what is added / supported so far in BigQuery Mate: `Ctrl-/` ; `Shift-Ctrl-/` ; `Ctrl-Enter` ; `Ctrl-Alt-/` ; `Shift-Ctrl-Alt-/` ; `F5` ; `F1` . See details in help section of extension’s popup (click on mate icon in browser’s right top corner)

Comment: Ahhh....great! So it is possible, but we just have to wait for it to be rolled out again!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried lots of different combinations, but to no avail! It would appear that there is no shortcut available for "Run Selected". You could raise a feature request [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/).

Comment: There is no! I am going to Add Shift-F5 for this for BigQuery Mate (in addition to current Mate's F5)

Comment: Wondrous news! I'm a massive BiqQuery Mate fan! As soon as it's live, I'll update my answer.

Comment: hey - i just added BigQuery Mate and ctrl+enter no longer works? also is F5 supposed to run the query aswell? Does nothing for me. Cheers

Comment: Google has just pushed "new" Web UI with ability of "run selected". If you see this new feature - make sure you have most recent Mate  - 1.5.63.

Comment: btw, looks like that new built of web ui broke a number of things on google side so new UI is up and down - making recent Mate's F5 not working for "old" version as it is adjusted (yesterday) for new version as I thought it is finally there - which looks like not!

Comment: just deployed 1.5.65 (should be available in chrome store shortly) - supposedly F5 should work for old and new web ui. cannot test for new as it is not showing anymore - i assume because there are few fixes to be applied to it on google side

Answer (score 0):

This feature was recently (yesterday?) re-released by Google, but shortcut was blocked by BigQuery Mate for those of you who are using it. Sorry for this.

It is just fixed now (v.1.5.72)
Note: I added Ctrl-F5 in addition to built-in Ctrl-E for "Run Selected"

I will check if there are other similar confilicts - but please comment if you see any.

Comment: Run Selected and other new features from recent Web UI update are again rolled back. A little annoying for me to stay in sync with Google for BigQuery Mate :o( will relax for a while unless some major issue with Mate